# Can I make the audio quieter, if it's already at 1%?

Tags: windows-7

I'm using a cheap USB sound card, which amplifies the sound something fierce. Rather than buy a new card, I would like to find a software solution to making it not as loud. I don't much care about the audio quality, just the volume.

Comment: Other than telling you to mute it, it would be helpful to know more about the sound card you're using.

Comment: There's not much to tell. The card is this one - http://www.amazon.de/gp/product/B00C7LXUDY/ - and the device hardware ID is USB\VID_0D8C&PID_013C&MI_00.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If 1% is too loud - you probably connected your computer to very low level input (microphone input) of your hi-fi system.

Windows volume settings depend on audio card drivers. Volume control "inside windows" is very precise (it operates on 32 bit numbers, it's huge overkill), audio card hardware, divers and interface (sliders etc) reduce it.

Some card drivers allow to control additional parameters, like output configuration (headphones, stereo, 5.1 etc.). Maybe changing these could help.

If you not have it - you can use [Volume Step Adjuster](http://sourceforge.net/projects/volstep/?source=typ_redirect) (unfortunately it works only with multimedia keys, not the slider). Readme says:

> Volume Step Adjuster allows you to adjust the increment/decrement step
>   of your system volume **when you use your multimedia keys**. By default,
>   this step is 2% or 4%, which may be not appropriate for high-precision
>   setting. With Volume Step Adjuster you can set this volume step to any
>   valid value, for example, you can set the volume step to 1% or even
>   0.1%. **The real volume step resolution available depends on your device**. Note, however, that this tool only configures
>   increment/decrement step. It does not adjusts increment/decrement
>   speed or any other parameters.

How to use:

1. Download it
2. Edit 'volstep_START.bat' script file (that come with program) and change `SET VOLUME_STEP=` to 0.1 or something like that.
3. Run volstep_START.bat script

You can see/verify volume settings with free [SoundVolumeView](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/sound_volume_view.html) tool.

I have tested this on my laptop sound card, it works perfect with volume control dedicated buttons, but you can expect diffrent behavior on diffrent sound cards.

If that will not help - you have to make/buy audio cable with some potentiometer(s) or resistors and adjust volume with hardware. You may try to ask [here](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/) how to make that kind of cable.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer; I'll give the Volume Adjuster a go and see how it works.

Comment: I think I made mistake, volume in windows is processed as 32 bit number, not 16. I corrected that in my answer.